# Calculate x/y Coordinates from Angle for every Point

Tags: math, coordinates

I want to order 28 Items in a Circle.
I have a given angle and a radius, with this I need to calculate my coordinates.
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: it's not clear, what do you exactly want. can't you add clarifications? what are you talking about?

Comment: I want to order 28 Button in a Circle. I want to calculate my coordinates to get a perfect circle, but I have no Idea how to do this. The button should be ordered like a clock.

Comment: [Polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system); see, particularly, Section _Converting between polar and Cartesian coordinates_. In your case, your angle increments between each button is `2π/28` (radians).

Comment: do you want to create 28 buttons, which will be in circle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple maths question, not a Swift question.

```
let circle = 2.0 * Double.pi
for angle in stride(from: 0.0, to: circle, by: circle / 28.0) {
    let x = radius * cos(angle)        
    let y = radius * sin(angle)
    // Add x & y to the coordinates of your centre.
}
```

Comment: For large datasets it may be worth computing only the first quadrant, and using the circle's symmetries to infer the rest. Sin and cos are pretty high latency on most archs